# <style> disabled not applied

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why doesn't the `disabled` property work when applied in HTML to a `<style>` section but it does work when applied via JS. In other words, if I have:

```html
<html>
  <style id="myStyle" disabled>
    body {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
        // document.getElementById("myStyle").disabled = true;
  </script>
  <body>
    Hello world!
  </body>
</html>
```

Then it will be white text on black background even though the `<style>` section has the `disabled` attribute. But if I uncomment the JS line, the style will be properly disabled and it will be black text on white background. I also tried `disabled="true"` and some other variants with no effect.

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the ``<head>`` tag? :)

Comment: I'm not sure about what JS does here, but, `disabled` is intended to make an element (most of the times inputs) not mutable, not focusable, and not interatible. The browser automatically puts things like `style` and `script` tags inside a `head` tag, so that's not the problem.

Comment: @Leo `document.getElementById("myStyle").disabled = true;` will disable the rules defined in that style tag, so that they are not applied. And this works, however, a `style` element does not have an attribute `disabled` it has only a property with that name.

Comment: @t.niese Have done it in several browsers right now, non of them puts the tags in the body.

Comment: @Leo ah yes, it depends where they are placed. If they appear before `<body>` they are added to `<head>` if they appear after `</body>` they are added to `<body>`.

Answer (score 2):

The style tag does not actually have a disabled property per the HTML spec https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3

```
<!ELEMENT STYLE - - %StyleSheet        -- style info -->
<!ATTLIST STYLE
  %i18n;                               -- lang, dir, for use with title --
  type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED -- content type of style language --
  media       %MediaDesc;    #IMPLIED  -- designed for use with these media --
  title       %Text;         #IMPLIED  -- advisory title --
  >
```

However, the dom spec does have a disabled property (https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-16428977):

```
interface HTMLStyleElement : HTMLElement {
           attribute boolean         disabled;
           attribute DOMString       media;
           attribute DOMString       type;
};
```

Thus your JS can change the DOM and disable the style tag, however, there is no way to disable the style tag directly from HTML.

Comment: Don't use images for textual content.

Comment: @Wakka, can't read it! Format it and I'll upvote you.

Comment: If you had a formatting improvement you should have edited it then.

Answer (score 0):

Style has no disabled attribute as per the spec.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3

> %i18n;                               -- lang, dir, for use with title
> --   type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED -- content type of style language --   media       %MediaDesc;    #IMPLIED  -- designed for use
> with these media --   title       %Text;         #IMPLIED  -- advisory
> title --

Also style is a Head Tag:

> The STYLE element allows authors to put style sheet rules in the head
> of the document. HTML permits any number of STYLE elements in the HEAD
> section of a document.